# How do I change the fixed values of days between two dates into variable and use event handler Javascript to show output?

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker, event-handling, dom-events

As the title stated, I would like to make a variable out of "2011-11-2","2011-11-05" which are the date start and date end

```
 <?php echo getWorkingDays("2011-11-2","2011-11-05",$holidays); ?>;
```

How do I change the fixed value of days between two dates into variable from business day calculation PHP function and using Javascript event handler to show an output?

When user selects date from the date picker from both textfield "DateFrom" and "DateTo" then user required to press the <kbd>Check Day(s)</kbd> button to calculate the number of the two date between that have been specified.

Below are the PHP function to get a business day between two dates:

```
<?php
function getWorkingDays($startDate,$endDate,$holidays){

$days = (strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate)) / 86400 + 1;

$no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
$no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);

$the_first_day_of_week = date("N", strtotime($startDate));
$the_last_day_of_week = date("N", strtotime($endDate));

if ($the_first_day_of_week <= $the_last_day_of_week) {
    if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 6 && 6 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
    if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 7 && 7 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
}
else {

    if ($the_first_day_of_week == 7) {
        $no_remaining_days--;

        if ($the_last_day_of_week == 6) {
            $no_remaining_days--;
        }
    }
    else {

        $no_remaining_days -= 2;
    }
}

$workingDays = $no_full_weeks * 5;
if ($no_remaining_days > 0 )
{
  $workingDays += $no_remaining_days;
}

foreach($holidays as $holiday){
    $time_stamp=strtotime($holiday);

    if (strtotime($startDate) <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= strtotime($endDate) && date("N",$time_stamp) != 6 && date("N",$time_stamp) != 7)
        $workingDays--;
}

return $workingDays;
}

$holidays=array("");
?>
```

When i echo the fixed value of date it works prefectly fine

```
    <?php echo getWorkingDays("2011-11-2","2011-11-05",$holidays); ?>;
```

Followed by javascript and form:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js">
    </script> 

    <form name=fname method='post'>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">Date From:</div></td>
      <td><div>
      <input id="dateFrom" type="text" name="DateFrom" class="tcal" value='' autocomplete="off" />
    </div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">Date To:</div></td> 
      <td><div>
          <input id="dateTo" type="text" name="DateTo" class="tcal" value="" autocomplete="off"/>
    </div></td>
    </tr>
    <p>
    <input id="leavetakens" name="leavetakens" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly">

    <input type="button" value="Check Day(s)" name="btnCalculate" onClick="abc()"></p>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function abc()
    {
var jsvar = <?php echo getWorkingDays("2011-11-2","2011-11-05",$holidays); ?>;

var dateFrom = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
var dateTo = document.getElementById("dateTo").value;

document.fname.leavetakens.value=jsvar

    }

    </script>
```

At this point I only can show the value from the fixed two date specified but how to make it as variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $workday=getWorkingDays("2011-11-2","2011-11-05",$holidays); ?>;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but its not quite what want exactly. What i meant is how to make a variable inside the function bracket like <?php $workday=getWorkingDays($dateFrom,$dateTo,$holidays); ?>; according to the form should i be using $_POST Variable in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to call a server/PHP function (i.e. `getWorkingDays()`) from the client/JavaScript side. You can achieve this via AJAX in `abc()`.

The full AJAX may look like this:

```
var dateFrom = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
var dateTo = document.getElementById("dateTo").value;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.fname.leavetakens.value = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getWorkingDays.php?dateFrom="+dateFrom+"&dateTo="+dateTo, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

where getWorkingDays.php takes two parameters, namely `dateFrom` and `dateTo`, in the querystring and call the PHP `getWorkingDays()` function, and then returns/writes the value.

If you use jQuery (or some other JavaScript library), it will significantly save your time and code:

```
var dateFrom = $("#dateFrom").val();
var dateTo = $("#dateTo").val();

$.get('getWorkingDays.php', {dateFrom: dateFrom, dateTo: dateTo}, function(data) {
    $('#leavetakens').val(data);
});
```

The getWorkingDays.php would look something like this:

```
<?php echo getWorkingDays($_GET["dateFrom"],$_GET["dateTo"],$holidays); ?>;
```